# Creating fragment in default tab crashes application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a typical actionbar setup (ActionbarSherlock) where my default tab is "Home".

When the app launches, the tab is selected. When the fragment is created/committed, it crashes the application.

The rest of the tabs creates/replaces the fragments properly, so it is probably not that part of the code. I suspect it has to do with the lifecycle process?

This is rather puzzling, would love some guidance.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  implements ActionBar.TabListener {    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    containerId = android.R.id.content;

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(homeTab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(questionsTab);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(newsTab);

    Tab [] tabs = new Tab []{homeTab, questionsTab, newsTab};
    stackManager = new StackManager(this, tabs)    }

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {        
    // this crashes the application
    if (tab.getText()== HOME) {
        this.loadFragment(new AppTabBFirstFragment("home"));
    }

   if (tab.getText()== QUESTIONS) {
        this.loadFragment(new AppTabBFirstFragment("qns"));
   }

   if (tab.getText()== NEWS) {
        this.loadFragment(new AppTabBFirstFragment("news"));
    }       
   }

public void loadFragment(Fragment frag){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(containerId , frag).commit();
```

// LOG CAT

[image]

Comment: May we have the LogCat (stack trace)?

Comment: @a-c thanks for that! very sorry for the error, i now know what the error is. I was setting the pointer to the fragment container AFTER I set up the tabs. I did not expect the tabselected to be called at the point of creation